# Ansible Json string how to get value other than up from json using json_query

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

```json
{
         "tunnel-ip79": "up",
         "tunnel-ip8": "up",
         "tunnel-ip80": "up",
         "tunnel-ip81": "up",
         "tunnel-ip82": "up",
         "tunnel-ip83": "up",
         "tunnel-ip84": "up",
         "tunnel-ip85": "up",
         "tunnel-ip86": "up",
         "tunnel-ip87": "down",
         "tunnel-ip88": "up",
         "tunnel-ip89": "down",
}
```

```yaml
- set_fact:
    tunnel_interface: "{{ interface | from_json | json_query(tun_int) | to_nice_json }}"
  vars:
    tun_int: "result.[*]"
```

I'm trying to get the value of JSON whose value is not "up" in my case, just to display whose key values are "down". so far I got up to here. any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> just to display whose key values are "down"

In a nutshell:

```yaml
---
- name: Show the list of down interfaces
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
 
  vars:
    # This is your example data on a single json line for compactness
    interfaces: {"tunnel-ip79": "up","tunnel-ip8": "up","tunnel-ip80": "up","tunnel-ip81": "up","tunnel-ip82": "up","tunnel-ip83": "up","tunnel-ip84": "up","tunnel-ip85": "up","tunnel-ip86": "up","tunnel-ip87": "down","tunnel-ip88": "up","tunnel-ip89": "down"}
   
  tasks:
    - name: Select the list of interface names in 'down' status
      # Transform dict to list of {key: x, value: y} pairs,
      # select only the needed elements and extract the key name
      set_fact:
        down_interfaces: "{{ interfaces | dict2items | selectattr('value', '==', 'down') | map(attribute='key') | list }}"

    - name: Show the result
      debug:
        var: down_interfaces
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [Show the list of down interfaces] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Select the list of interface names in 'down' status] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show the result] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "down_interfaces": [
        "tunnel-ip87",
        "tunnel-ip89"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```